# Find max value for each year in 3D array NetCDF file (way to use Pandas or xarray?)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, max, netcdf

I am trying to makes some maps and such of data from several NetCDF files. Each one contains data for 5 years worth of data. The data is in a 3D array of shape `(14608, 145, 192)` (time, lat, lon).

I would like the maximum value for each year at each coordinate, so basically when it's all said and done I'll have an output array with shape `(5,145,192)` (one value per each lat. and lon. value).

It has been suggested I try using pandas, specifically DataFrame and DatetimeIndex, but I couldn't find a way to use it for more anything greater than a 2D array. Xarray was also suggested, but I haven't used xarray before and wouldn't know where to start.

**Edit 1: Sample Data**

Here is a simplified version of what I've been trying to do with pandas and then I realized DataFrame doesn't work for a 3D array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fake = np.random.randint(2, 30, size = (14608,145,192))
index = pd.date_range(start = '1985-1-1 01:30:00', end = '1989-12-31 22:30:00' , freq='3H')

df = pd.DataFrame(data = fake, index = index)
```

**Edit 2: Fixed Listed Array Shape**

To clarify, I actually want an array with shape `(5, 145, 192)` as the output. I wrote it wrong because originally I was splitting the 3D array into 5 separate arrays, finding the max, and then stacking them again into one array witch ended with a shape of `(5, 145, 192)`.

I want to be able to skip the tedious breaking apart the array by hand, so to speak, that I was doing before and simplify the code.

Comment: Can you make some sample data

Comment: I added a simplified version of the code I was using with DataFrame with some fake data.

Comment: Adding a solution for you

Comment: Just to clarify your question, you state you want the annual maximum value, but then you state: "I'll have an output array with shape (145,192) (one value per each lat. and lon. value)."  - This is inconsistent as you have 5 years of data i.e. you should have (5,145,192) - please can you clarify your question whether you want annual maximum or the maximum over the whole 5 years.

Comment: I want annual maximums, so one value per year per coordinate. I guess my explanation in the question wasn't very clear. The way I was doing before using pandas, I split the everything by hand, essentially, for each year, and ended up with 5 separate arrays that I then put back together using `np.stack`. So yes you are correct I want (5,145,192), sorry for confusion I wrote it wrong and will fix.

Comment: @AlexMorrison, see my answer below which describes how to calculate annual maximums using xarray's resample or groupby functionality.

Comment: Gosh, you don't want/need to split anything by hand, that's what computers are for ;-) ;-)   If you want to have one big file for all the years you can simply merge the five-year files together first with cdo mergetime file_*.nc merged_file.nc and then use the cdo command below to give you the max each year.  It is two commands from the command line, you don't even need to open python.  Facilities such as CDO and NCO (and Ferret) are designed to take all the work out of these kind of statistical calculations on netcdf files - rather than write code from scratch each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could approach this using Xarray:

```
import xarray as xr

# open one of your files
ds = xr.open_dataset('path/to/your/ncfile.nc')

# find maximum for a specific year (1990 in this example)
ds_ymax = ds.sel(time=slice('1990-01-01', '1990-12-31')).max('time')

# plot a single variable ('temperature' in this example)
ds_ymax['temperature'].plot()
```

While that covers the basics of what you're trying to do, there are a few other common workflow things I figured I should mention:

1. [Open multiple files at once](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/io.html#id11). Xarray provides a `open_mfdataset` function that allows for quick concatenation of multiple files at once:

   ```
   ds = xr.open_mfdataset('path/to/your/ncfiles/*nc')  # note the use of the wildcard
   ```
2. Using [resample](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations) to calculate annual maximum values. In my example above, I manually selected a single years worth of data but it is possible to do this programmatically using resample or groupby

   ```
   # using resample ('AS' == annual starting Jan-1)
   ds_ymax = ds.resample(time='AS').max('time')

   # using groupby
   ds_ymax = ds.groupby('time.year').max('time')
   ```

Finally, you mentioned not knowing where to start with xarray. Take a look at the documentation: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: This totally helped and thank you for the link. That also helped! I was able to get things working thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can using `Panel` here

```
df = pd.Panel(fake).to_frame()
df.columns=index
df
Out[1065]: 
             1985-01-01 01:30:00  1985-01-01 04:30:00  1985-01-01 07:30:00
major minor                                                               
0     0                       28                    7                   22
      1                        9                   10                   11
      2                        8                   15                    7
      3                       19                   18                    2
      4                       14                   16                   24
      5                        6                   26                   13
      6                       28                   16                   11

#....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct python solution, but if you want annual maximum (i.e. one value for each grid point per year) then you can do this from the command line with `cdo`:

```
cdo yearmax in.nc out.nc
```

You can use these functions from within python by using the cdo  package, installed with:

```
pip install cdo
```

Further details here: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html